# Geometry Nodes select faces with 2 neighbours if neighbours are on edges next to each other

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to make a face selection with Geometry Nodes and I need help translating to vector maths-node language the following: select those faces that have two neighbouring faces but only if the two face neighbours have at least one vertex in common. On the attached image I've marked red the faces I'd like to select.

This is a street network and I need to delete the crossings, including corners of "L" turns. These corners are a bit trickier to define and I don't have a deep enough understanding of vector maths nodes to put this together.

[image]

[image: faces with two face neighbours]

Comment: to attract more people to your question i recommend providing a blend file so we don't have to rebuild everything manually. You want help right? so i would - if i were you - make it as easy as possible for those people, who are willing to answer you for free in their spare time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you want?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes indeed, this is what I need, works beautifully, many thanks for helping out. How would I know to set the second delete node's context to point instead of face?